# Maximum of a Markov process is a Markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}, P)$ is a Probability space, and $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a $1$-dimentional continuous Markov process.

I want to know whether $Y_t := \text{max}_{0\leq u \leq t}X_u$ is a Markov process or not.

I predict $Y_t$ is a Markov process because the information needed to determine the value of $Y_t$ within $\mathcal{F}_t$ is based on when does $X_u$ attains its maximum value for $u \in [0, t]$. In this case, it is sufficient to consider the sigma-algebra generated by $\max_{0 \leq u \leq t} X_u$.

All I have to prove is that $\forall \Gamma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}_s$,
$$
P\left(\{\text{max}_{0\leq u \leq t + s}X_u \in \Gamma\} \cap A\right) = E\left[P\left(\text{max}_{0\leq u \leq t + s}X_u  \in \Gamma \,| \,\text{max}_{0\leq u \leq s }X_u\right), A\right]
$$
but what should I do after this?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you assume that it never works. This is not possible. Consider, for example, the (somewhat stupid) Markov process $X_t = 1$ a.s. for all $t\geq 0$. Then, $Y_t = 1$ a.s. and therefore also a Markov process. Instead, you might want to simply find an example where it doesn't work, so that you can say that, in general, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
However, while I was thinking about it, I changed my question because I feel that my expectation that it is not a Markov process is not correct. Please take a look at it and advise me again.

Comment: Also, while it doesn't apply directly to your problem, when $d=1$ the running maximum of a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ is rather informative.

Comment: Intuitively, I  think that if $X_t$ has independent increment property, then $Y_t$ is likely to possess the Markov property. Therefore, when X is a random walk, Markov property seems plausible. However, I cannot prove it. Measure theory is challenging for me.

Comment: In short, no, $Y_t$ need not possess the Markov property.  The reason, at an informal level, is that knowing $Y_t > Y_s$ for every $s < t$ tells you that $Y_t = X_t$, in which case $Y_t$ is more likely to increase (since $X_u > X_t$ is sufficient for $Y_u > Y_t$)

Comment: Thank you very much.
To give a simple example, if we consider the third step in a random walk, with two patterns, +-- and -++, the former has  $Y_4 = Y_3$ a.s., while the latter has $Y_4 > Y_3$ with probability 1/2, right?

Comment: And this leads $Y_t$ is not Markov process when $X_t$ is a random walk.